# datetime vs timestamp in mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, timestamp

What is the difference between datetime and timestamp in MySQL with respect to data being inserted from different timezones? Does anyone have any clues on this?

I have a situation where I am trying to migrate from db2 to mysql. In DB2 a field is referred to as timestamp but MySQL's timestamp does not support values greater than 2038-01-19 03:14:07, so I have used datetime. Before implementing datetime I want to do an impact analysis.

Comment: You do know the differences are documented in the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name told on his comment, the differences are documented in [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), but here is some information:

## Size:

`datetime` - uses 8 bytes for each field

`timestamp` - uses 4 bytes for each field (half of the size)

## Range:

`datetime` - `1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`

`timestamp` - `1970-01-01 00:00:01` UTC to `2038-01-19 03:14:07` UTC

## Timezone:

as @ypercube mention, `timestamp` converts your data to utc and store it, and when you retrieve it, it converts from utc to your timezone connection.

## Concept:

`datetime` - Is a calendar date(same point in time can be different depends on timezone).

`timestamp` - Is a point in time, does not matter the timezone your are.

## Suggestion:

The 2 main differences are `range` and `size`, then think, do you really need dates bigger then `2038-01-19 03:14:07` at the moment(at the moment, no in the future!)?
If no, go with `timestamp` for now, when you reach a point where you need a date range outside `timestamp` range, convert it to `datetime`.

Comment: What do you mean with *"`datetime` is a calendar date."*?

Comment: And another major difference is that: *"MySQL converts `TIMESTAMP` values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as `DATETIME`.)"*

Comment: I updated the answer, It's kinda of you said about the timezones.